# Determine the Dimension of $U:=\{A\in\textrm{Mat}(2\times 2,\mathbb{R}):AB=BA\}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> Given $B\in \textrm{Mat}(2\times 2,\mathbb{R})$
>
> $B=\begin{bmatrix}
>     1       & 1  \\
>     0      & 1 
> \end{bmatrix}$
>
> Determine the dimension of $U:=\{A\in\textrm{Mat}(2\times 2,\mathbb{R}):AB=BA\}$

I already know that $U$ is a Subspace of $\textrm{Mat}(2\times 2,\mathbb{R})$, but I have no idea how I could start with determining a Basis or the dimension other than educated guessing.

Comment: $U$ is the subspace of all matrices that commute with $B$.  Which matrices A commute with B?

Comment: In the absolute worst case, you could consider the matrices to be elements of $\mathbb{R}^4$ and determine the kernel of the operator $A \mapsto AB-BA$.

Comment: Why not simply make linear equations . The no. of free variables will give you the dimension of U.

Comment: Thanks! I found out that $\textrm{dim}(U)=2$ applying your technique @Lord KK

Comment: This is done very easily from Module theory. The dimension only depends on the similarity class of $B$. In this case, one eigenvalue with geometric multiplicity $1$. Thus, the dimension is $2$.

Comment: @i707107 interesting to see such elementary problems trough a more advanced lense!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given

$B = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}, \tag 1$

we may write $B$ as

$B = I + N, \tag 2$

where

$N = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}; \tag 3$

then we have

$AB = BA \Longleftrightarrow A(I + N) = (I + N)A \Longleftrightarrow A + AN = A + NA \Longleftrightarrow AN = NA; \tag 4$

setting

$A = \begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{bmatrix}, \tag 5$

we compute

$AN =  \begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & a \\ 0 & c \end{bmatrix}, \tag 6$

and

$NA = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{bmatrix} =  \begin{bmatrix} c & d \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}; \tag 7$

comparing (6) and (7) we see we must have

$c = 0, \; a = d; \tag 8$

$b$ is apparently unconstrained; thus $A$ takes the form

$A = \begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ 0 & a \end{bmatrix} = aI + bN; \tag 9$

we have shown that the form (9) is a *necessary* condition for $AB = BA$; it is clear it is also *sufficient*, since the matrices $N$ and $I$ commute, $NI = N = IN$:

$AB = (aI + bN)(I + N) = aI + aN + bN + bN^2 = aI + (a + b)N, \tag{10}$

$BA = (I + N)(aI + bN) = aI + bN + aN + bN^2 = aI + (a + b)N, \tag{11}$

where we have used the fact $N^2 = 0$ in (10)-(11).

It follows that $I$ and $N$ form a basis for $U$, and that

$\dim U = 2. \tag{12}$

Comment: Good morning Sir!

Comment: @copper.hat:    And a jolly good morning to you,  Where you caffienating at?  Myself the mundane Starbucks!

Comment: The mourning period is not over yet :-). I can only caffienate in private :-).

Comment: @copper.hat:   Mourning puns for the morning!;)

Comment: Triple pun there...

Comment: Thanks for putting in so much effort into the response!

Comment: @ChristianSinger:  my pleasure sir!

Answer (score 2):

Standard tricks are to look at standard matrices such as $I$, and look at
matrices composed of outer products of eigenvectors.

So, we see that $I \in U$. Note that $B e_1 = e_1$, and so $e_1 e_1^T \in U$.

The following are just 'educated' guesses:

If we choose $P$ to be the non identity permutation matrix, we see that $P \notin U$.

Note also that $e_2 e_2^T \notin U$ and this does not lie in the $\operatorname{sp} \{I,P\}$.

The only choices for dimension are $0,1,2,3,4$.